# Best Practices for creating a VM with GPU inside Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, continuous-integration, virtual-machine

I am currently building a CI pipeline to benchmark new Machine Learning models. For this I use a Azure DevOps Pipeline.

This pipeline runs on a standard Azure VM without a GPU. To run these models though I need a GPU. My idea was to create (inside the build process) a VM with a GPU in Azure and run the model and all the benchmarking scripts there and then return the results and destroy the GPU VM.

What are the best-practices for doing this (az cli or Terraform for example)?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use az cli to do this. Before you can use Azure Cli task in your pipeline. Your Azure subscription must be configured to your Azure devops in the [Service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in the Project settings page.

Then you can just add a Azure Cli task in your build pipeline and run the below [az image create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az-image-create) command to create the VM.

```
az vm create \
 --name ${AZ_VM_NAME} \
 --resource-group ${AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP} \
 --image ${AZ_IMAGE} \ --location ${AZ_LOCATION} \
 --size ${AZ_SIZE} \ --ssh-key-value ${AZ_SSH_KEY} \
 --admin-username ${AZ_USER} \
 --nsg ${AZ_NSG}
```

You need to [prepare your VM variables](https://docs.nvidia.com/ngc/ngc-azure-setup-guide/launching-vm-instance-using-azure-cli.html#preparing-instance-variables) and select a [GPU image](https://docs.nvidia.com/ngc/ngc-azure-vmi-release-notes/)

When you want to destroy the GPU VM, you can add another Azure Cli task at the end of your pipeline to run [az image delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az-image-delete).

```
az vm delete -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP -n $AZ_VM_NAME
```

And also [delete other associated resouces](https://docs.nvidia.com/ngc/ngc-azure-setup-guide/launching-vm-instance-using-azure-cli.html#deleting-vm-resources-cli) eg. OS disk, network interface, Ip address

```
az network nic delete -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP -n MyNic

az disk delete -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP -n MyDisk 

az network public-ip delete -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP -n MyIp
```

If you would like to use Azure Powershell task to do above tasks, you can check [this examples.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/new-azvm?view=azps-3.1.0) Azure powershell might be easier to get the associated resources and delete them when you delete the VM. You can refer to [this example](https://adamtheautomator.com/remove-azure-virtual-machine-powershell/)

To Deploy VM using ARM template, please check the [this detailed tutorial](https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/iac/200.2x-IaCLabsM03ARM.html). It shows you how to create ARM template and how to deploy it.

Note:

> In case you encountered not authorized error when running above scripts.

Please check **allow scripts to access token** for the agent job

[image]

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would still need to copy my repository to this newly created GPU VM and build and run the Docker Container there. What is the best way to do this inside the pipeline? (I would need to save the VM IP adress for example to access it from the pipeline somehow)

Comment: If you want to build and run docker container there, You can create a [self hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) hosted on this VM, in this way you can assign the agent to run your pipeline in azure devops pipeline, and the agent hosted on the VM will then build and run the container.

Comment: Hi @Sharif Elfouly Did you tried  creating your own self-hosted agent? How was it going?